# Correct way to do Create and Update actions for one to many objects in .Net Core Ef Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on my first .Net Core application and I was able to put together the CRUD actions for my first table.

The second table has a foreign key to the first table and I think I've gone off on the wrong path in trying to put together the Create and Update actions. The Update action needs to pass in all items from the foreign key table for the user to select from. But as an update Action, the View needs to have the actual objects foreign key selected from the drop-down list.

What's the correct way to do this? I can't seem to find a consistent answer on Google.

Table 1 Model:

```
 public class HTMLElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Element { get; set; }
    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomizedElement> CustomizeHTMLElements { get; set; }
}
```

Table 2 Model:

```
public class CustomizedElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? HTMLElementId { get; set; }
    public HTMLElement HTMLElement { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel for Table Two:

```
public class CustomizedHTMLElementViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HTML Element")]
    public int HTMLElement { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "HTML Elements")]
    public ICollection<HTMLElement> HTMLElements { get; set; }
}
```

Create Controller:

I want to pass in all of the items from Table 1 into the view for a drop-down list that the user can select from and this works but not sure if it's the correct way to do this.

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddCustomizedHTMLElement()
    {
        var elements = new CustomizedHTMLElementViewModel
        {
            HTMLElements = db.HTMLElements.ToList()
        };

        return View(elements);
}
```

The Post action is working but not sure if it's the most efficient.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult AddCustomizedHTMLElement(CustomizedHTMLElementViewModel CHTMLEV)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var element = db.HTMLElements.Single(e => e.Id == CHTMLEV.HTMLElement);

        CustomizedElement cElement = new CustomizedElement()
        {
            Name = CHTMLEV.Name,
            HTMLElement = element,
        };
        db.CustomizedElements.Add(cElement);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CustomizedHTMLElements");
    }
    return View(CHTMLEV);
}
```

I'm having a really hard time with the Update action. I want to pass in all foreign keys but also have the objects foreign key selected in the drop-down list in the View

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UpdateCustomizedHTMLElement(int Id)
{
    var mElement = db.CustomizedElements.Include(e => e.HTMLElement).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == Id);
    ViewBag.ElementsList = db.HTMLElements.ToList();
    return View(mElement);
}
```

I haven't worked on the Update actions [HttpPost] yet until I get the View right.

Update View:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Templates" asp-action="UpdateCustomizedHTMLElement">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name"></label>:
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" asp-for="Name" />
        <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HTMLElement"></label>:
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.HTMLElement, new SelectList(ViewBag.ElementsList, "Id", "Element"), new { @class = "form-control" })
         <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="HTMLElement"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
         <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CustomizedHTMLElements", "Templates")'">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class UpdateCustomizedHTMLViewModel
{
   public int SelectedHtmlElementId { get; set;}
   public CustomizedElement ElementToUpdate { get; set;}
   public ICollection<HTMLElement> HTMLElements { get; set;}
}
```

Then fill ElementToUpdate and HTMLElements in your get and when you select the HTMLElement you want to update with in the dropdown you assign that Id to SelectedHtmlElementId

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment.  Consider commenting when you have the rep.  If you'd like to answer the question, please provide a complete answer.